# How to stop a terminal process running code including threading?

Tags: python, linux, multithreading

I am using threading to run multiple functions at the same time with the purpose of pulling weather data from multiple websites. I ran these these programs through the Linux terminal, however am unable to cancel them by pressing ctrl C. I want to have them run for an indefinite amount of time, and as such do not want to add in a finish time, but would rather cancel them when necessary. Does anyone know why ctrl C is not cancelling them, and how to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Daemon Threads

It may be tempting to simply use daemon threads to solve this problem, a python execution will stop when **only** daemon threads are left, and will **not** allow them to clean up nicely. [The docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#thread-objects) call this out clearly:

> Daemon threads are abruptly stopped at shutdown. Their resources (such as open files, database transactions, etc.) may not be released properly. If you want your threads to stop gracefully, make them non-daemonic and use a suitable signalling mechanism such as an Event.

Let's follow their advice and use an Event.

### Using an Event

An event is a simple flag that can safely be set and read across threads. In this case, we will create an event in the main thread, spawn a new thread to do some work, and listen to that event flag in case it should stop working.

```
import threading

ended = threading.Event()

def do_work():
    while not ended.is_set():
        # Do your repeated work
        pass

# Let's create and start our worker thread!
new_thread = threading.Thread(target=do_work)
new_thread.start()

try:
    while not ended.is_set():
        ended.wait(1)
except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
    print("Cancelling")
    ended.set()
```

The try/catch block here runs in the main thread, listening for a `KeyboardInterrupt` or `SystemExit` exception. If it catches one, it will set the `stopped` flag, allowing the thread to complete its current loop iteration, and perform any cleanup it needs to.

Answer (score 5):

1. Use `Ctrl + Break` key combo.
2. Press `Ctrl + Z`. This will not stop program but will return you the command prompt. Then, do `ps -ax | grep *%program_name%*`. Find the line corresponding to the one yopu want to stop. The first integer in line will be program ID. Do `kill -9 %id%` to finally stop it.
3. If program also eats a lot of resources, you can use `top` command in a separate terminal to see the ID faster.

[Reference](https://askubuntu.com/questions/150616/ctrlc-does-not-quit-a-running-program-in-terminal)

Comment: 1. Ctrl + Break did not work.  2. Possibly worked(I'm rather new to linux and working in terminal and trying to figure stuff out), however I am trying to write the collected data to a text file and this causes me to lose the data.

Comment: While this technically is an effective way of ending the python program, a `kill -9` is not a graceful way to end it. There are better alternatives.